# fetch users data from database in node

Tags: node.js

I am currently learning nodeJS and I am able to make a user connect or disconnect to a user area, but I would like to display his infos from the database and I'm not sure how I can proceed

```
  app.get('/profil', function(request, response) {
    // If the user is loggedin
    if (request.session.loggedin) {
        // show the home page of logged users
        username = request.session.username
        catfood = request.session.catfood
        password  = request.session.password
        email = request.session.email
        var sql = "SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE username = '"+ username + "'";
        connection.query( sql, function ( err, resultSet ) {

            if ( err ) throw err;
        
            //console.log( resultSet );
            catfood = resultSet[0].catfood;
            
        
        });
        
        //connection.end();
        response.render('loggedin/profil', )
        response.end();
          
        
    } else {
        // Not logged in
        
        response.send('Please login to view this page! <a href="login">login</a>');
    }
    response.end();
});
```

profil.ejs :

```
<div class="max-w-screen-lg bg-white shadow-2xl rounded-lg mx-auto text-center py-12 mt-4">
<h2 class="text-3xl leading-9 font-bold tracking-tight text-red-800 sm:text-4xl sm:leading-10">
<%= I would like to display, like, his username, etc %>
</h2>
```

I am normally a PHP dev, but trying to learn a new back end language.
For example, in PHP, you would do :

```
$req = $bdd->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = :user");
$req->bindValue('user',$username, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$req->execute();
$user = $req->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
echo $user->username;
```

How to do the same in nodeJS ?

Answer (score 0):

You should do render with in the query callback, like this:

```js
        connection.query( sql, function ( err, resultSet ) {

            if ( err ) throw err;
        
            //console.log( resultSet );
            catfood = resultSet[0].catfood;
            
            response.render('loggedin/profil', {catfood: catfood});
            response.end();
        });
```

Now you can use the `catfood` object in your template.

Comment: Nope, it creates a  `Cannot create property '_locals' on number '83'` error
I think you meant : 
`response.render('loggedin/profil', {'catfood': catfood})`

Answer (score 0):

I managed to do it.
You had to:

`app.js`:

```js
var sql = "SELECT * FROM drops WHERE username = '"+ username + "'";
connection.query(sql, function (err, resultSet) {
    response.render('loggedin/index', {
        user: resultSet
    });
});
```

`index.js`:

```ejs
<% user.forEach(function(o) { %>
    <%= o.username %> - <%= o.cat %> <br>
<% }); %>
```

without the loop if you don't need to go through a loop